# Ondraw called only once

Tags: android, draw

I call the draw class in a loop to draw a bunch of lines but i only got one line 
here's the draw class :

```
class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        paint.setColor(colorr[thecolore[0]]);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawLine(clickat[0], clickat[1], clickat[2], clickat[3], paint);
                            clickat[0] = -1;
                            clickat[1] = -1;
                            clickat[2] = -1;
                            clickat[3] = -1;
    }
}
```

(I pass some dynamic float to the table clickat) 
I have this loop :

```
for(int i=0; i<regenlinks[myposition].length;i+=8){

    if(regenlinks[myposition][i] !=-1 ){

        clickat[0] = X+30;
        clickat[1] = Y+30;
        clickat[2] = (float)regenlinks[myposition][i+3];
        clickat[3] = (float)regenlinks[myposition][i+4];
        thecolore[0] = (int)regenlinks[myposition][i+5];

        RelativeLayout mapView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayou);

        DrawView drawView = new DrawView(maps.this);
        drawView.setId((int)regenlinks[myposition][i+6]);
        mapView.addView(drawView);
    }
}
```

but the only line who was drawing when the loop ends is the last one. Any ideas why ?

Comment: you have to add the view to a `ViewGroup`  to be drawn because the onDraw method is only invoked by a `ViewGroup` which will provide a canvas to draw on , in your case you have to add the view to mapView : mapView.addView(drawView, ...// layout params )

Comment: It's just a copy paste error i do have an             mapView.addView(drawView);
in the end !

Comment: I don't see it, it must be inside the loop !!

Comment: Voila! in my code i do have it , same problem !

Comment: I think you have to specify the second parameter of the addView method  to specify the position of the the view in the ViewGroup, cause addView will use default parameters that can be the same for each drawView so they will be overlapped

Comment: canvas.drawLine(clickat[0], clickat[1], clickat[2], clickat[3], paint);i pass the position of the line i draw  the drawline that's not enough ?

Comment: How does the DrawView class get the clickat array?

Comment: the clickat arrays are dynamicly added , to be more specific i have the Matrix regenlinks where i have the X1 , Y1 and the X2,Y2 of the lines in each line of the matrix so what i do is i loop the matrix lines and i put the Xs and Ys in Clickat

Comment: See my answer - though it assumes that you are passing clickat correctly to DrawView. "the clickat arrays are dynamically added..." does not in any way answer my question. I still don't know how DrawView gets access to clickat.